# How can I display Calendar Agenda on Mac Outlook 2016?

Tags: ms-office, calendar, mac

On Windows Microsoft Outlook I'm used to being able to display a pane to the right of the Mail screen showing:

- Calendar
- Agenda

[image]

Is it possible to display this on Mac Microsoft Outlook 2016? And if so, how can I do this?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-calendar-view-98716767-479e-4f2e-8fc2-e722e99fa8b1 may be of interest